# The effects of dual booting on performance

Tags: hard-drive, performance, multi-boot

Say I have Windows 7 but want to dual boot Ubuntu(or you know, anything else). Does downloading Ubuntu effect performance when I use Windows or, while not in use, does it just sit there and take up bit more space on my hard drive(or even an external drive)?

Comment: The latter. There's minimal performance impact apart from disk space used when in dual-boot.

Answer (score 3):

The main potential performance impacts on a PC come from CPU and memory usage.

When dual booting, the active OS is active, consuming memory and CPU, while the other OS is entirely inactive.  It does not use any CPU or memory.

The only resources the other OS uses is hard disk space.  This would have no impact to performance if the main OS has disk space to use.